# Perl if-statements / regular expressions

Tags: regex, perl, if-statement

I'm not entirely sure why my if-statements are not validating user input. Here's my code.
The statements that contain regular expressions are supposed to allow leading, and trailing white space.

```
sub     Menu
{

    &processlist;
    &creating_Refs;

    print "[Sort by COLUMN|sortup|sortdown| quit]:";
    my $user_input = <STDIN>;
    chomp($user_input);

    if($user_input =~ m/[quit\s]/)
    {
            exit;
    }
    elsif($user_input eq 'sortup')
    {
            print "working bro\n\n";
            @$VAR1 = sort sortup @$VAR1;

            foreach my $ref (@$VAR1)
            {
                    print "$ref->{PID}, $ref->{USER}, $ref->{PR}, $ref->{NI}, $ref->{VIRT}, $ref->{RES}, $ref->{SHR}, $ref->{S}, $ref->{CPU}, $ref->{MEM}, $ref->{TIME}, $ref->{COMMAND} \n";
            }
    }
    elsif($user_input eq 'sortdown \n')
    {
            print "working on sortdown\n\n";

    }
    elsif($user_input =~ m/[sort by]+\w/)
    {


    }
    else
    {
            print "Error, please re-enter command \n\n";
            &Menu;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A character class like `[abcd]` allows any **one** of the characters specified in the square brackets. When you say `[sort by]`, it is equivalent to `/s|o|r|t| |b|y/`, which will match any one of those characters, only once. If you want to match `sort by`, use `/sort by/`.

And in your case:

```
if($user_input =~ m/quit/){
    exit;
}
```

and to match exact words use word boundaries:

```
if($user_input =~ m/\bquit\b/){
    exit;
}
```

Comment: After changing all my if-statements to the same syntax of `if $user_input eq 'whatever' ` Everything worked. Thank you sir.

Comment: That also matches `quitter`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($user_input =~ m/quit/){
    exit;
}
```

Also chomp removes trailing \n

So:

```
elsif($user_input eq 'sortdown \n')
```

Will never be true.